# Can't create new build environment in Sublime 2

Tags: command-line, build, path, sublimetext2

Using Command-B from with Sublime Test 2 works for me, but it does not use the latest version of Ruby. I'm trying to fix that.

Repro steps:
1) Go to tools|build system|new build system
2) Paste the following code:

```
{
    "cmd": ["~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

Now when I press Command-B, I get the following (notice the 'u' prepended to each of the commands):

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby', u'/Users/$USERNAME$/projects/blog/yadda.rb']]
[dir:  /Users/$USERNAME$/projects/blog]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

NOTE: This is not a dupe of the other articles on Sublime 2 builds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I type:
~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby /Users/$USERNAME$/projects/blog/yadda.rb
from the command line, it works. Something is fouling things up by prepending a 'u'.

Comment: The 'u' indicates that it's treated as a Unicode string, so it's definitely not "fouling things up". The error message seems to suggest that Sublime is unable to find the Ruby compiler or your file. Have you checked permissions for `"~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby"` (should be world-executable) and `/Users/$USERNAME$/projects/blog/yadda.rb` (should be world-readable)? What user are you running Sublime as?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
"cmd": ["~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"]
```

with

```
"cmd": ["/Users/your_username/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"]
```

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work. The individual commands work fine (at the command line). The problem is that Sublime is adding a 'u' to them when it runs them. See above:

[cmd:  [u'~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby', u'/Users/$USERNAME$/projects/blog/yadda.rb']]

Comment: What do you get, if you type `which rvm-auto-ruby` in a terminal?

Comment: It hangs (because I'm not passing in a filename). But when i type rvm-auto-ruby [file_location] it runs properly. Sublime is adding a u to the commands. That's the only problem. I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Please, type `which rvm-auto-ruby` on the terminal (with `witch`). This is to know where `rvm-auto-ruby` is located

Comment: Oh. Gotcha. Shows up under /users/$USERNAME$/.rvm/bin.